# Vim Colour Theme Problem

Tags: vim

My goal "was" to set the text-width persistently to 72.  I seem to be only able to achieve this by creating a custom .vimrc file.  However when I did that, I immediately ran into a colour scheme issue where my comments were no longer blue (even though the only option I set was "set textwidth=72" in the file).  To demonstrate, this is how my window looks before I create a .vimrc file:

[image: without a vimrc file]

If I create a .vimrc file and enter the below, all my comments turn white:

```
set textwidth=72
```

As such I then tried to fix the colour of the text by adjusting the colours using the below .vimrc file:

```
colorscheme default
syntax enable
set background=dark
set textwidth=72
```

The result is that my colour for my comments is fixed, althought I dont entirely understand it yet, it appears to be fixed:
[image]

But then when I go to edit my vimrc file, the colours are as follows:

[image: Actual VIMRC]

My question is why is it different?  I can't tell what is working properly and whats not working properly.  Like is my test file not working properly, or is the vimrc file working properly, and whats the issue?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question "is my test file not working properly, or is the vimrc file working properly, and what's the problem?", this is the expected behavior of the vimrc file.

From the help pages in vim:

> The defaults.vim file is loaded when the user has no vimrc file.  When you create a new vimrc file, add this line near the top to keep using it:
>
> `source $VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim`

The defaults.vim file turns on various options, including syntax highlighting, as you have noticed. But, once a user creates their own `vimrc` file, as suggested by the text from the help file above, unless the user explicitly says to use the defaults.vim file, it is not read, meaning that only the options that are specified in the new vimrc file are used.

This is precisely the reason that in the help pages (`:help vimrc-intro`), it is recommended to add the line

> source $VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim

to your vimrc file, so unwanted changes do not take place.

Comment: This does not solve the issue